# Local uniqueness of Cauchy Problem, but can it split into branches?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, cauchy-problem

The problem I've been struggling is exemplified here:

[Is local Lipschitz continuity sufficient for an ODE to have a unique solution?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1441492/is-local-lipschitz-continuity-sufficient-for-an-ode-to-have-a-unique-solution/1441495#1441495)

The problem that they solve is

\begin{align*}
x'(t) = x^2,\quad x(0) = x_0
\end{align*}

which in the other thread is said to have a unique solution given by

\begin{align*}
x(t) = \frac{1}{x_0^{-1}-t}.
\end{align*}

This function is not continuous at $t = x_0^{-1}$ bu they claim in the other thread that it is unique in $(-\infty,x_0^{-1})$, supposing $x_0>0$. Since $f(x,t) = x^2$ the function is only locally Lipschitz and therefore we are only guaranteed a unique solution locally? How can one in general be sure that it does not split into separate branches outside of some small interval?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Local uniqueness already garantuees uniqueness on the whole intervall of existence. Let me give a short proof:

Let $u_1$ and $u_2$ solve the same initial value problem. Let us also assume there exists a $t\in\mathbb{R}$ such that for every $\varepsilon>0$ we find an $\tilde{t}\in(t,t+\varepsilon)$ such that $u_1(\tilde{t})\neq u_2(\tilde{t})$ and $u_1(t)=u_2(t)$. This means $u_1$ and $u_2$ are equal up to $t$, but after that $t$, they may differ. Local uniqueness now gives us a small open neighborhood of $t$ in which $u_1$ equals $u_2$. Hence we find an $\tilde{\varepsilon}>0$ such that for every $x\in(t,t+\tilde{\varepsilon})$ we have $u_1(x)=u_2(x)$. If you choose you $\varepsilon$ now to be smaller than $\tilde{\varepsilon}$ you obtain a contradiction.

Your example is also unique up to the point of existence. Please note, that your $x(t)$ tends to $\infty$ if $t\uparrow x_0$. Hence your solution cannot be extended further and therefore it cannot branch. (See also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinary_differential_equation#Global_uniqueness_and_maximum_domain_of_solution)

Comment: Ok I understand your reasoning, but don't we need equality on a closed set? Altough I guess that this also follows since if $u_1(t) = u_2(t)$ on $(a,b)$ then due to continuity $u_1(b) = u_2(b)$. Thank you very much for your help.