# Global existence and uniqueness of a locally Lipschitz IVP

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, analysis, partial-differential-equations, dynamical-systems, lipschitz-functions

This is a question on global existence and uniqueness for an IVP. Consider the following first-order nonlinear ODE (known as a Ricatti equation):

\begin{align}
y^{\prime} = f_1(x) y^2 + f_2(x) y + f_3(x),\qquad x\in [0,\infty)\tag{1},
\end{align}

subject to a boundary condition

\begin{align}
y(0) = y_0.\tag{2}
\end{align}

Let $f(x,y) = f_1(x) y^2 + f_2(x) y + f_3(x),$ i.e., let $f:[0,\infty)\times (-\infty,\infty)\rightarrow (-\infty, \infty)$ be the right hand side of (1). Assume that $f$ is *locally Lipschitz* in $y$. From [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1441492/is-local-lipschitz-continuity-sufficient-for-an-ode-to-have-a-unique-solution), it appears that local Lipschitzness guarantees that a global solution is unique iff a global solution exists.

My question is the following: Do Ricatti equations (in particular those defined for an unbounded time domain) always have solutions? Presumably, if my statements were correct, then (1)-(2) would have a unique global solution. I ask this question because I have a problem with only local Lipschitzness, not global, so existence is an issue. Some IVPs have solutions that blow up in finite time and cannot be extended globally. I am hoping that in the case of this particular type of ODE this is not an issue.

Comment: With "global solution" you mean a solution (cont. differentiable) that has $[0,∞)$ as domain? If $f_1(x)$ is negative, this might be possible. In the other case it will depend on the initial value and how fast the root curves of the right side move, that is, how similar the right side is to the constant coefficient case.

Comment: @LutzLehmann Yes, I should have been more clear. I mean a continuously differentiable solution $y(x)$ with $[0,\infty)$ as its domain. What if $f_1(x)$ is a constant for all $x$?