# Can locally Lipschitz ODE system imply bounded solutions?

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, stability-in-odes

Consider a system of first-order ODE
$$\dot{x}=\Phi(x).$$

1. $\Phi(x)$ is locally Lipschitz. [By the theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1441492/is-local-lipschitz-continuity-sufficient-for-an-ode-to-have-a-unique-solution), given any initial condition $x(t_0)=x_0$, the solution $x(t)$ is unique and continuous on some interval $[t_0, T)$, where $T\in \mathbb{R}\geq t_0$.
2. Somehow, $x(t)$ has the property $$\|x(t)\|\leq te^t.$$ Thus, $x(t)$ is unique and continuous in the interval $[t_0, \infty)$.

My question is, can $x(t)$ be bounded on $[t_0, \infty)$ with what we have so far? If not, then what do we need more to ensure boundedness of the solution?

Comment: $\dot{x} = x$ is unbounded.

Comment: Bounded on $[t_0,\infty)$? No. Just take $\Phi(x)=x$, then for $t_0=0,x_0=1$, the unique solution is $x(t)=e^t$, which is clearly unbounded.