# How to determine Lipschitz continuity of a differential equations of R^2

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, lipschitz-functions

We have the following differential equation $F(t,c)$, where as $c=(x,y)$

\begin{cases}
\dot{x}(t) = |x(t)| - y(t) \\
\dot{y}(t) = 3 - 2x(t) - y(t)^2
\end{cases}

How do I determine if $F(t,c)$ is Lipschitz continuous regarding $c$ within some closed interval $[-\delta,\delta]$ with $\delta>0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact, suppose $x_1,x_2,y_1,y_2\in(-\delta,\delta)$. Then, for $c_1=(x_1,y_1),c_2=(x_2,y_2)$, one has
$$\begin{eqnarray}
|F(t,c_1)-F(t,c_2)|&=&|(|x_1|-y_1,3-2x_1-y_1^2)-(|x_2|-y_2,3-2x_2-y_2^2)|\\
&=&|(|x_1|-|x_2|-(y_1-y_2),-2(x_1-x_2)-(y_1^2-y_2^2)|\\
&=&||x_1|-|x_2|-(y_1-y_2)|+|-2(x_1-x_2)-(y_1^2-y_2^2)| \\
&\le&||x_1|-|x_2||+|y_1-y_2|+2|x_1-x_2|+|y_1+y_2||y_1-y_2| \\
&\le&|x_1-x_2|+|y_1-y_2|+2|x_1-x_2|+2\delta|y_1-y_2| \\
&=&3|x_1-x_2|+(2\delta+1)|y_1-y_2|\\
&\le&(4+2\delta)|x_1-x_2|+|y_1-y_2|\\
&=&(4+2\delta)|c_1-c_2|
\end{eqnarray}$$
and hece $F$ is Lipschitz.

Comment: I forgot to say that the closed interval  of $[-\delta,\delta]$ goes for t. But that shouldn't change  anything right? Because if $t$ is bounded so should $(x,y)$ be bounded. Is that correct?

Comment: That is right. $F$ is Lipschitz w.r.t $c$.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1441492/is-local-lipschitz-continuity-sufficient-for-an-ode-to-have-a-unique-solution?rq=1